# Why the JavaScript primitives are not an instance of their constructors?

Tags: javascript, numbers, prototype, instance, primitive

Here's a snapshot of what I've tested on the Firefox console. Why is; '**a instance of Number**', gives false, while 'object instance of Object' is true? Does this mean, the variable "a" is a primitive and not a child of Number() constructor?

[image: Image - Console output]

Comment: "*Does this mean the variable `a` is a primitive*" - yes. `instanceof` only works with objects

Comment: If you check the docs for `instanceof` you'll see that it refers to the prototype chain, which is established for objects but not for primitives.  A number might have a constructor, but it doesn't have a `prototype`, and so `instanceof` fails.

Comment: Thanks @DaveMeehan. But when I enter __proto__ of the number (ex. a.__proto__), it works. Doesn't this mean the number has a prototype?

Comment: Try `const a = 1;

console.log(a.__proto__ === a.constructor.prototype)
console.log(a.prototype === a.constructor.prototype)`.  __proto__ is not analagous to prototype in the case of a primitive. Primatives don't have `prototype` so don't work with `instanceof`